# Apply tangent law on scalene triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle,ABC, what is the measure of angle A if the side opposite of angle A is 3 and the adjacent side to angle A is 4?
VarsityTutor solved it with tangent formula (opposite/adjacent). But I think it's unsolvable because the triangle is not right or another adjacent side isn't given. 
What is your opinion about it?

Comment: The tangent formula you described would only apply if the third side of the triangle was the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  Could you provide a link to the actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite such triangles are possible .One can not determine angle A . For a unique triangle given data is insufficient

-